# Domain name shows IP address

Tags: apache, dns, digital-ocean

I have a debian server with Apache installed which is hosted with Digitalocean.
I have A record that directs to the my server IP and CNAME record that's the alias of A record. Now when I put my domain in the browser and hit enter, the url changes to public IP. Not sure why?

Records are as follows

```
|type  | hostname       | value          | TTL(seconds)
|CNAME | www.domain.com | domain.com.    | 43200
|A     | domain.com     | 123.45.678.945 | 3600
```

Comment: Can't say much without knowing the records

Comment: @McAden please see my edited question.

Comment: My suspicion would be a redirect or a mixup in your hosts file. Either way I think this question may belong on serverfault

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

Turned out WordPress was the culprit.

This answer helped me: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/domain-redirects-to-ip-address-and-also-loading-from-ip-address#answer_6213

> Log into your WordPress Dashboard & navigate to Settings. What's listed as your Site URL & Home URL?

I had IP address listed there and not domain name.